# Cheap flights in the Nuremberg area?

Tags: air-travel, germany, bavaria, nuremberg

I've heard that the airport in Nuremberg is very expensive, so the cheap flight lines are preferring to fly from other airport nearby. Unfortunately, I've failed to remember the name of that other airport.

From where in the Nuremberg area you can fly with cheap lines?

Comment: One of the cheapest airlines in Europe (Ryanair) flights indeed from and to Nuremberg main airport

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no other "interesting" airport really nearby. At 172 kilometers you have the [Allgäu Airport in Memmingen (FMM)](http://www.allgaeu-airport.de/). This airport is sometimes called "Munich West" and served by some low-cost carriers. You have to go by [bus](http://www.busliniensuche.de) or [train](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/) from Memmingen to Nürnberg. It takes almost 4 hours. Bus prices start at 11 EUR and trains at 19 EUR (if you book early enough). Add 3 EUR for the transfer from the airport to the city.

Another interesting option can be [Franz Joseph Strauss Airport (MUC)](http://www.munich-airport.de), next to Munich. It's 132 kilometers from Nuremberg. It is a huge airport served by plenty of airlines. It is a bit closer to Nuremberg than Memmingen, and you have better possibilities to make the transfer by public transport. You can either take a [train](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/) or a [bus](http://www.busliniensuche.de/). A regional train costs 22 EUR and it takes 2h45 with one change. Buses are faster (< 2 hours) and probably cheaper, but less frequent than the trains.

Comment: It is possible that in was Memmingen. Well, probably the transport there would cost more than the flight itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Google Flights: https://www.google.com/flights/
First type-in Nuremberg as the destination, and then press "+" inside that destination box to add other nearby airports sorted by distance from the main one. It'll automatically show you all the nearby airports and tickets for all of them. It's pretty amazing. 
Another awesome thing about that tool is that it always shows FULL price including all the taxes, and it'll give direct airline number to book if you find something.

Comment: "Sorry, flights from Germany are not currently supported." yeh sure amazing...

Comment: And major companies are missing too: Lufthansa, Easyjet, Swiss, Ryanair ...

Comment: Just reverse the direction - since you were interested in nearby airports that'd do the trick.
It does include Lufthansa, Swiss, etc, etc. etc. - look at the Airline dropdown (it also displays only ones that have those routes)